# ASP.NET webreferences/servicereferences for WCF

Tags: asp.net

A couple of questions:

Is App_WebReferences for WCF schema files? Should this not be App_ServiceReferences?

Also, what is dynamic compilation in ASP.NET?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fb46ye(VS.80).aspx):

> App_WebReferences folder   Contains
>   files used to create a reference to a
>   Web service (in the same project or
>   external to the project), including
>   .disco and .wsdl files

There's no special folder in ASP.NET called `App_ServiceReferences`.

As far as dynamic compilation is concerned you may take a look at [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366723.aspx) which explains it very good.